# EXPLAIN INSERT showing different possible keys on different executions

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm attempting to troubleshoot a slow INSERT query using EXPLAIN EXTENDED. The problem, I think, is that the keys are not being used properly. Executing EXPLAIN EXTENDED on the same query multiple times will result in different results. In the background there are no crons running, this is on a staging server so no traffic right now besides me, and there are no table schema changes happening.

The Query:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (
  `attribute_id`,
  `store_id`,
  `value`,
  `row_id`
)
VALUES
  (
    '442',
    '0',
    'https://www.example.com/item/',
    '46242'
  )
  ON DUPLICATE KEY
  UPDATE
    `attribute_id` = VALUES(`attribute_id`),
    `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`),
    `value` = VALUES(`value`),
    `row_id` = VALUES(`row_id`);
```

The explain query:

```
explain extended
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (
  `attribute_id`,
  `store_id`,
  `value`,
  `row_id`
)
VALUES
  (
    '442',
    '0',
    'https://www.sexample.com/item/',
    '46242'
  )
  ON DUPLICATE KEY
  UPDATE
    `attribute_id` = VALUES(`attribute_id`),
    `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`),
    `value` = VALUES(`value`),
    `row_id` = VALUES(`row_id`);
```

EXPLAIN Response 1:

```
    id  select_type  table                           partitions  type    possible_keys                                                                        key     key_len  ref       rows  filtered  Extra   
------  -----------  ------------------------------  ----------  ------  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ------  -------  ------  ------  --------  --------
     1  INSERT       catalog_product_entity_varchar  (NULL)      ALL     CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_STORE_ID  (NULL)  (NULL)   (NULL)  (NULL)    (NULL)  (NULL)
```

EXPLAIN Response 2:

```
    id  select_type  table                           partitions  type    possible_keys                                                                        key     key_len  ref       rows  filtered  Extra   
------  -----------  ------------------------------  ----------  ------  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ------  -------  ------  ------  --------  --------
     1  INSERT       catalog_product_entity_varchar  (NULL)      ALL     CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ROW_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_STORE_ID  (NULL)  (NULL)   (NULL)  (NULL)    (NULL)  (NULL)
```

EXPLAIN Response 3:

```
    id  select_type  table                           partitions  type    possible_keys                                                                        key     key_len  ref       rows  filtered  Extra   
------  -----------  ------------------------------  ----------  ------  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ------  -------  ------  ------  --------  --------
     1  INSERT       catalog_product_entity_varchar  (NULL)      ALL     CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID  (NULL)  (NULL)   (NULL)  (NULL)    (NULL)  (NULL)
```

And a few times, possible_keys has come back blank.

I suspect when the optimizer chooses the key in Response 2 it is a fast insert. What would cause EXPLAIN response to change like this?

Version Information:

```
aurora_version           2.11.1                        
innodb_version           5.7.12                        
protocol_version         10                            
slave_type_conversions                                 
tls_version              TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2         
version                  5.7.12-log                    
version_comment          MySQL Community Server (GPL)  
version_compile_machine  x86_64                        
version_compile_os       Linux
```

Table CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (
  `value_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID',
  `attribute_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute ID',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store ID',
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Value',
  `row_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Version Id',
  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ROW_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID` (`row_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`),
  KEY `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID` (`attribute_id`),
  KEY `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_VCHR_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_VCHR_ROW_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ROW_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`row_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`row_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=567985353 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Varchar Attribute Backend Table'
```

Row Count 2,813,210 rows.

Finally, this is happening on other tables as well, not just this one.

This is happening on both production and staging, but it seems to be happening on staging more.

Comment: insert use no indexes, it only update the indexes

Comment: Exactly .. inserts are fast .. Updates require it to think and determine.  It might be better to make 2 seperate procedures and only run the insert when its a new record and the update when its a real update.

Comment: @nbk -- IODKU must check all unique keys (2 in this table) for which values are specified.

Answer (score 0):

The table has 2 unique indexes.  IODKU must check any of them for which values are being provided.

```
PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),                     -- no check needed
UNIQUE (`row_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`),  -- checked
```

2 cases:

- If a row with that triple exists, it will be `UPDATEd`.
- If no such row exists, the data will be `INSERTed'.

Did your different experiments have different values?

I have never used `EXPLAIN` on IODKU -- it is so obvious what needs to be done that the `EXPLAIN` won't tell me anything useful.

I think that the `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_STORE_ID` case is a bug; suggest filing a report at bugs.mysql.com